# Logistic Regression, error for divide by zero

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, curve-fitting

It works well but not learning anything.The loss goes never down.Besides, it occurs a Runtime Warning: Divide by zero encountered in power.

```py
phi = np.array([0, 0.00724873038246, 0.0126062332691, 0.0179158239032, 0.0237780447692, 0.0301819694947, 0.037412389363, 0.0453824653196, 0.0541722382861, 0.0638498928693, 0.0748241181818, 0.0870018575601, 0.100969984201, 0.116901498992, 0.135225153396, 0.155865741879, 0.179184255267, 0.205004290279, 0.233612351761, 0.265481420095, 0.307980863])
kf = np.array([188.0535454, 200.042702173, 212.031762644, 224.020823148, 236.009883356, 247.998943263, 259.988002683, 271.977061559, 283.96611989, 295.955177493, 307.944233912, 319.933288966, 331.922341978, 343.911392444, 355.900439242, 367.889482121, 379.878519645, 391.867551768, 403.856577188, 415.845593859, 427.834570885])
PHI_train = torch.FloatTensor(phi)
KF_train = torch.FloatTensor(kf)

def ludwig_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a+b*(x**c)

class Reg(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,n_feature,n_hidden,n_output):
        super(Reg, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Linear(1,16)
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Linear(16,8)
        #self.layer4 = torch.nn.Linear(32,16)
        self.predict = torch.nn.Linear(8,3)

    def forward(self,x):
        x = F.relu(self.layer1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.layer2(x))
        x = self.predict(x)
        return x
reg = Reg(n_feature = 1, n_hidden = 16, n_output = 3)

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(reg.parameters(),lr=0.01)
loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()

for epoch in range(200):
    PRM = reg(PHI_train) #Tensor
    prm = PRM.detach().numpy() #Array

    for i in range(len(ludwig_prm)): #length of prm = 21

        a = prm[i,0]
        b = prm[i,1]
        c = prm[i,2]
        #d = prm[i,3]
        preds = ludwig_func(phi,a,b,c)#Array
        np.set_printoptions(precision=10)
        preds = np.nan_to_num(preds)
        #print(preds)

        Preds = torch.FloatTensor(preds)#Tensor
        Preds[Preds == float('inf')] = -0.2e+10
        #print(Preds)

        loss = loss_func(Preds,KF_train) #Tensor
        loss[loss == float('inf')] = 0.1e+29
        loss = Variable(loss,requires_grad = True)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    print('Epoch:',epoch+1,'MESloss:',loss.item())
```

I have struggled this for a long time and don't know why. On the Internet i have also nothing found. It will be so nice, that someone could help.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow! I am trying to reproduce your code, what is F ?

Comment: @MatteoPeluso I think it's torch.nn.functional.

Comment: Try fitting a straight line - that should work, and is a very fast test to make.

Comment: and ludwig_prm?

Comment: If it might be of some use, I obtained a better fit than your code's equation by using a Michaelis-Menten equation with an offset, "y = (a * x) / (b + x) + offset", with parameters a = 3.5059952394383146E+02, b = 1.4101439190139128E-01, and offset = 1.8549158547747004E+02 yielding RMSE = 1.398 and R-squared = 0.9996

Answer (score 0):

Hi your problem is in the definition of the input arrays, if you try to change it in as example:

```
phi = Variable(torch.Tensor([[10.0], [9.0], [3.0], [2.0]]))
kf = Variable(torch.Tensor([[90.0], [80.0], [50.0], [30.0]]))
```

the procedure will work

In my opinion you have to reshape your inputs